# React Joyride: steps skipping, tooltip not showing, reset not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've spent a few hours trying to get to grips with [React Joyride](https://docs.react-joyride.com/), but have some problems. I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/joyride-controlled-broken-103wk) to demonstrate the difficulties I'm having:

1. When I click 'next' the tooltip changes to a beacon, but I don't want it to and I don't understand why this happens on this step and not subsequent ones?
2. It also skips Step2 (stepIndex 1). Why does it do this and how do I stop it?
3. When I reset my stepIndex to `0` and set run to `true` I would expect the tooltip to show at Step 1. Why has this not happened?
4. When I click 'back', it doesn't go back. Joyride behaves as if I clicked 'next'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/discussions/663) from the creator.

1. **When I click 'next' the tooltip changes to a beacon, but I don't want it to and I don't understand why this happens on this step and not subsequent ones?**

*Not sure why it was happening (probably because the Joyride component was rendered again between state changes).
But the callback was called twice with the type EVENTS.STEP_AFTER and index 0 so it increased the stepIndex twice. 0 -> 2*

*Change the conditional to:*

`else if (data.index === stepIndexState && (type === EVENTS.STEP_AFTER || type === EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND))`

2. **It also skips Step2 (stepIndex 1). Why does it do this and how do I stop it?**

(answered with point 1)

3. **When I reset my stepIndex to 0 and set run to true I would expect the tooltip to show at Step 1. Why has this not happened?**

*It is happening.*

4. **When I click 'back', it doesn't go back. Joyride behaves as if I clicked 'next'.**

*Since you are controlling the tour you need to take the `action` in consideration.*
`setStepIndexState((prev) => prev + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Your sandbox is not working properly, check it

Comment: Thanks. Incredibly frustratingly I appear to have lost all my work. Will repair and get back...

Comment: Yup, it's working now. I see an if statement for EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, but I don't see statement for EVENTS.STEP_BEFORE, maybe that's the problem?